# centos 7 : which при запуске из cron

Tags: centos7, sh

есть скрипт с содержанием

```
 #!/bin/sh

## Checking that cifs-utils package installed
CIFS=$( which mount.cifs | wc -l )
printf "CIFS = $CIFS \n" | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
if [ "$CIFS" -ne 1 ]; then
  printf "ERROR: cifs-utils package not installed!\n" | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
  exit 1
fi
```

при запуске из bash или sh руками все хорошо, но при запуске его через cron

> CIFS = 0  ERROR: cifs-utils package not installed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для crone

[

> The default path is set to PATH=/usr/bin:/bin. If the command you are
>   calling is present in the cron specified path, you can either use the
>   absolute path to the command or change the cron $PATH variable. You
>   can't implicitly append :$PATH as you would do with a regular script.
>   ][1](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/)

А для which

[

> DESCRIPTION
>          Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been
>   executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt. It
>   does this by searching for an executable or script in
>          the directories listed in the environment variable PATH using the same algorithm as bash(1).
>   ][2](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which)